# proper handling of plugins (modules) in autotoos/libtool

Tags: shared-libraries, autotools, libtool

I have a project that generates a static lib L. Some function of L has the ability to load some pluggins M (using `dlopen("libmmmm.so")`: M is a shared lib (module)).

The test T testing the `module_load()` function of L is made of the main test T (to which L is staticaly linked) and a pluggin M, to test its loading in T+L.

The tests are part of the installation (testdir is defined).

Here follows the Makefile.am in test T's directory (building both T and M):

```
#the test program linked with the static lib L:   
#(the tests are distributed as well, hence the test_* prefix)                                  
test_PROGRAMS = tttt                                       
tttt_SOURCES = tttt.c
tttt_LDADD = llll.la

#the module to be loaded by the T+L test:                                                     
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmmmm.la                                        
libmmmm_la_SOURCES = mmmm.c                                 
libmmmm_la_LDFLAGS = $(AM_LDFLAGS) -module -shared
```

The problem is regarding the path at which the module can be found:
The test works (i.e. libmmmm.so is found) for make check. But fails for out of tree (VPATH) builds (shared lib not found).

So the question:
How is it supposed to work? libtool has to set something like LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I guess, as `dlopen()` will never understand the `*.la` wrapper...

So what does it do and how can I fix this so it works all times, i.e. make check, out of tree build, make distcheck...
Hard coding a search path into the `.libs` directory does not feel very portable: We use autotools because we target many different platforms.

PS: I am aware that the "lib" prefix of M could be omitted due to the "-module" option

Comment: @Diego's advice is the way to go. `libltdl` is not encumbered by the GPL if your software is built with `libtool`. It's portable, and attempts to emulate functionality if not provided by a specific platform. Modules are briefly mentioned in the [`automake`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Libtool-Modules) manual. A more detailed overview of `automake` and `libltdl` is found in the [`libtool`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Using-libltdl) manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `libltdl` to take care of it, that one does understand `.la` files, and that will fix the loading, but it's not 100% the same API.

I'm afraid that otherwise, you'll have to write your own wrapper scripts to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in this situation.

Comment: actually still problem with @Diego's advice: Got: "undefined reference to `lt__PROGRAM__LTX_preloaded_symbols'" when Linking library L. It looks like autools want to know about the -dlopen option already when linking L! But only the test T knows that! so I now have the "-dlopen mmmm.la" option on the tttt_LDAD line... Can libltdl be used when building a LIB? (i.e. before the module to be loaded is known).

Comment: But the ldl lib has a symbol called lt_libltdl_LTX_preloaded_symbols...Is this supposed to be the same as lt__PROGRAM__LTX_preloaded_symbols???